# Beefing up capacity of existing AAG cluster

Tags: performance, availability-groups, perfmon

I am planning to add 3 new databases to an existing AAG cluster in a VM. The AAG has Veeam databases on it as of now. Veeam backups are not running on it as of now apart from a couple of batch processes of Veeam. I ran the PAL tool to figure out if memory was under pressure because SQLserver is consuming almost 93% of memory. I checked the page life expectancy and it looked OK. The Veeam team told me they had some performance issue and this is what i got from the PAL tool.

[image]

[image]

Do you think i need to add more memory to the VM? To make sure that the other 2 applications would just run fine. One of them is really light weight. But the other one is quite intensive

So I ran the following perfmon for almost a week, and this is where I am getting alerts. After changing the Max memory setting from default to 19gb

[image]

The following counters were run

•   Memory: Available Bytes
•   Memory: Pages/sec
•   Process: Working Set
•   SQL Server: Buffer Manager: Buffer Cache Hit Ratio
•   SQL Server: Buffer Manager: Total Pages
•   SQL Server: Memory Manager: Total Server Memory (KB)

Comment: what is the max memory and how many instances are running + Total RAM on the server ? What version of sql server you are using ? Is the network less than 1Gbps ? You also want to look at your disk latencies.

Comment: Actually the min max memory settings for this server have been setup wrong. The max memory setting is  2147483647 megabytes, but the server only has 24575 megabytes.

Comment: You are better off [changing the max memory to a more sensible value](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47218/8783). Also, depending on how busy the database is - 24GB RAM is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it's a good idea first to decrease the max memory, see how the application is working and then increase the physical memory size to accommodate the new databases?